# Output converted from matrix to vector in apply

Tags: r, matrix, apply

I want to apply a function over one margin (column in my example) of a matrix. The problem is that the function returns matrix and `apply` converts it to vector so that it returns a matrix. My goal is to get three-dimensional array. Here is the example (note that `matrix()` is not the function of interest, just an example):

```
x <- matrix(1:12, 4, 3)
apply(x, 2, matrix, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
```

The output is exactly the same as the input. I have pretty dull solution to this:

```
library(abind)
abind2 <- function (x, ...)
  abind(x, ..., along = dim(x) + 1)
apply(x, 2, list) %>% 
  lapply(unlist) %>% 
  lapply(matrix, nrow = 2, ncol = 2) %>% 
  do.call(what = 'abind2')
```

I believe there must exist something better than this. Something that does not include `list()`ing and `unlist()`ing columns.

---

**Edit:**
Also, the solution should be ready to be easily applicable to any-dimensional array with any choice of `MARGIN` which my solution is not.

This, for example, I want to return 4-dimensional array.

```
x <- array(1:24, c(4,3,2))
apply(x, 2:3, list) %>% 
  lapply(unlist) %>% 
  lapply(matrix, nrow = 2, ncol = 2) %>% 
  do.call(what = 'abind2')
```

Comment: the same as in the first example

Comment: see also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13811133/4137985)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not that complicated at all. Simply use

```
array(x, dim = c(2, 2, ncol(x)))
```

Matrix and general arrays are stored by column into a 1D long array in physical address. You can just reallocate dimension.

---

OK, here is possibly what you want to do in general:

```
tapply(x, col(x), FUN = matrix, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)

#$`1`
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    4
# 
#$`2`
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    5    7
#[2,]    6    8
#
#$`3`
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    9   11
#[2,]   10   12
```

Comment: The example function `matrix()` is not the function of interest. This is just the simplest function that returns a matrix I can imagine. I understand this might be confusing -- will edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to convert your `matrix` into a `data.frame` and use `lapply` to apply your function on the `columns` (as a `data.frame` is a `list`), it will return a `list`, where each element represents the function result for a `column`:

```
    lapply(as.data.frame(x), matrix, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)

    # $V1
         # [,1] [,2]
    # [1,]    1    3
    # [2,]    2    4

    # $V2
         # [,1] [,2]
    # [1,]    5    7
    # [2,]    6    8

    # $V3
         # [,1] [,2]
    # [1,]    9   11
    # [2,]   10   12
```

**EDIT with the second definition of `x`:**

```
x <- array(1:24, c(4,3,2))
lapply(as.data.frame(x), matrix, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
# $V1
     # [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    2    4

# $V2
     # [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    5    7
# [2,]    6    8

# $V3
     # [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    9   11
# [2,]   10   12

# $V4
     # [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   13   15
# [2,]   14   16

# $V5
     # [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   17   19
# [2,]   18   20

# $V6
     # [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   21   23
# [2,]   22   24
```

**EDIT2: a try to get an arry as result**

Based on [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811133/apply-a-function-to-each-layer-of-a-3d-array-returning-an-array), you may try this code:

```
x <- array(1:24, c(4,3,2))
sapply(1:3, 
       function(y) sapply(1:ncol(x[, y, ]), 
                          function(z) matrix(x[,y,z], ncol=2, nrow=2), 
                          simplify="array"), 
       simplify="array")
```

Dimension of the result is `2 2 2 3`.

Actually, the problem here is that it needs two different calls to apply when x is an array of more than 2 dimension. In the last example of the quesion (with `x <- array(1:24, c(4,3,2))`), we want to apply to each element of third dimension a function that apply to each element of second dimension the matrix function.

Comment: This was my first thought but it can be hardly extended. See my edit

Comment: So I guess I'll have to keep re-dimensioning the arrays after the `apply()` is called

Comment: it is easier to do cuts in arrays, e.g. `x[,1,]`